# glfw Errors with glfwWindowHint

Tags: c++, linux, g++, glfw

I have tried fallowing [this](http://open.gl/context) tutorial and it did not work. I do not know why it is not working. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and GNU G++ command.

code:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void) {
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); 
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);


    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", NULL, NULL);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
}
```

terminal:

```
command: g++ display.cpp -lglfw -o display.out
/tmp/cci33O9I.o: In function `main':
display.cpp:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
display.cpp:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
display.cpp:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
display.cpp:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
display.cpp:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
display.cpp:(.text+0x73): undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
display.cpp:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to `glfwMakeContextCurrent'
display.cpp:(.text+0xa2): undefined reference to `glfwWindowShouldClose'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not link to `glfw`, but link to `glfw3`. As here:

```
g++ display.cpp -lglfw3 -o display.out
```