# Use a library and header files in Gnome Builder

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, gnome-builder

**UPDATE** I switched to the meson build system.  Everything is working fine now!

I am very new to using C++, OpenGl, and Gnome Builder.  I have a very very basic foundation with C++ and I know how to link header files and libraries in CodeLite, however after messing around Gnome Builder I want to make the switch. I haven't found any beginner friendly tutorials on using Builder. I am just lost as to how I should link external libraries in Builder.  Do I just manually edit the Makefile or is there a setting somewhere that will automate the makefile process with automake?  Am I wrong in assuming that this is a makefile problem?  Apologies if this is a very novice question.

I am using Ubuntu.  I am getting the error "undefined reference to ..." for all the glfw and glew variables and headers. After installing libraries with apt, I have my libraries installed in usr/lib/x86-64-linux-gnu, headers in usr/include.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>


int main ()
{
  glewExperimental = true;
  if (!glfwInit() )
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW \n");
    return -1;
  }
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

  GLFWwindow* window;
  window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Tutorial 01", NULL, NULL);
  if ( window == NULL )
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. \n");
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
  }
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
  glewExperimental = true;
  if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to Initialize GLEW. \n");
    return -1;
  }

  glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

  do {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
  }
  while ( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS && glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);

 return 0;
}
```

When trying to build I get this error output~

> g++ -o practice -Wall -ggdb -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O2 practice.cpp
>   /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccLx11Ky.o: in function `main':
>   /home/joe/Projects/practice/practice.cpp:30: undefined reference to`glewExperimental'
>   /usr/bin/ld: /home/joe/Projects/practice/practice.cpp:31: undefined reference to `glfwInit'
>   /usr/bin/ld: /home/joe/Projects/practice/practice.cpp:36: undefined reference to`glfwWindowHint'
>   /usr/bin/ld: /home/joe/Projects/practice/practice.cpp:37: undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
>   /usr/bin/ld: /home/joe/Projects/practice/practice.cpp:38: undefined reference to`glfwWindowHint'
>   /usr/bin/ld: /home/joe/Projects/practice/practice.cpp:39: undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
>   /usr/bin/ld: /home/joe/Projects/practice/practice.cpp:40: undefined reference to`glfwWindowHint'
>   /usr/bin/ld: /home/joe/Projects/practice/practice.cpp:43: undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
>   /usr/bin/ld: /home/joe/Projects/practice/practice.cpp:50: undefined reference to`glfwMakeContextCurrent'
>   /usr/bin/ld: /home/joe/Projects/practice/practice.cpp:51: undefined reference to `glewExperimental'
>   /usr/bin/ld: /home/joe/Projects/practice/practice.cpp:52: undefined reference to`glewInit'
>   /usr/bin/ld: /home/joe/Projects/practice/practice.cpp:58: undefined reference to `glfwSetInputMode'
>   /usr/bin/ld: /home/joe/Projects/practice/practice.cpp:65: undefined reference to`glfwWindowShouldClose'
>   /usr/bin/ld: /home/joe/Projects/practice/practice.cpp:61: undefined reference to `glClear'
>   /usr/bin/ld: /home/joe/Projects/practice/practice.cpp:62: undefined reference to`glfwSwapBuffers'
>   /usr/bin/ld: /home/joe/Projects/practice/practice.cpp:63: undefined reference to `glfwPollEvents'
>   /usr/bin/ld: /home/joe/Projects/practice/practice.cpp:65: undefined reference to`glfwGetKey'
>   /usr/bin/ld: /home/joe/Projects/practice/practice.cpp:47: undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [Makefile:8: practice] Error 1

My default Makefile looks as follows~

```
all: practice

WARNINGS = -Wall
DEBUG = -ggdb -fno-omit-frame-pointer
OPTIMIZE = -O2

practice: Makefile practice.cpp
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(WARNINGS) $(DEBUG) $(OPTIMIZE) practice.cpp

clean:
    rm -f practice

# Builder will call this to install the application before running.
install:
    echo "Installing is not supported"

# Builder uses this target to run your application.
run:
    ./practice
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the build command (practice) to include the required libraries. Conside using `pkg-config --libs glew` (or `pkg-config --libs -static glew`) to find which libraries are needed, and `pkg-config --cflags` for command line flags, if any.

Most likely:

- Add '-lglfw3' to the 'practice' build command,
- If you use static libs, add '-DGLEW_STATIC'

See [glfw Errors with glfwWindowHint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816908/glfw-errors-with-glfwwindowhint), and [GLEW Linker Errors (undefined reference to `__glewBindVertexArray')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384510/glew-linker-errors-undefined-reference-to-glewbindvertexarray)

Comment: Thanks.  Are you familiar with Gnome Builder?  I am wondering if there is an IDE specific way that will add the libraries.  If not, I'll just edit the Makefile directly.